# CSS3 custom radio button issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, radio-button

i following the wittysparks.com create the custom radio button anything work fine,but if add more Content in label will show unused images.

code like below is working find.

```
    <input id="radio2" name="groupradio" type="radio" value="Radio 2" tabindex="6" /><label     for="radio2">I am Group Radio 2 </br>
</label>
```

after add more content in code will come out the problem.

```
    <input id="radio2" name="groupradio" type="radio" value="Radio 2" tabindex="6" /><label    for="radio2">I am Group Radio 2 </br>
I am Group Radio 2 </br>
I am Group Radio 2 </br>
I am Group Radio 2 </br>
I am Group Radio 2 </br>
I am Group Radio 2 </br>
I am Group Radio 2 </br>
I am Group Radio 2 </br>
I am Group Radio 2 </br>
</label>
```

this is my css

```
/*!
 * WittySparks - (c) Sravan Kumar, freely distributable, can modify as per your needs.
 * WittySparks.com.com
 */
input[type='radio'], input[type='checkbox']{opacity:0;position:absolute;filter:alpha(opacity=0);margin:5px 0 0 5px}
input[type='radio']:focus+label, input[type="checkbox"]:focus+label{color:#C30}
input[type="checkbox"]+label, input[type="radio"]+label{background:url('wittysparks_checkbox_radio.png') left top no-repeat;position:relative;margin:0;padding:0 0 0 50px;cursor:pointer;line-height:43px;min-height:43px;display:inline-block;z-index:0;font-size:30px;font-weight:bold}
input[type="checkbox"]+label{background-position:0 0}
input[type="radio"]+label{background-position:0 -200px}
input[type='checkbox']:checked+label{background-position:0 -100px}
input[type='radio']:checked+label{background-position:0 -300px}
input[type='checkbox']:disabled+label{background-position:0 -400px;color:#999}
input[type='radio']:disabled+label{background-position:0 -600px;color:#999} 
input[type='checkbox']:disabled:checked+label{background-position:0 -500px;color:#999}
input[type='radio']:disabled:checked+label{background-position:0 -700px;color:#999}
```

Tutorial web-sites.
"http://www.wittysparks.com/2012/04/17/pure-css3-custom-checkbox-and-radio-buttons-with-sprite-image/"

Update jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/fdEHj/1/

Comment: post your CSS as well .

Comment: hello Shivan Raptor i have post my css upside.thank you

Answer (score 0):

The CSS itself is affected by the height of label. If the height of label reduces to 1 line or two, the problem vanishes.

Try to separate the effect of label by CSS.

Comment: hi Shivan Raptor i have using "selectivizr-min.js" to hack the IE browser. and ":focus" function is work fine in ie7 and ie8 .thx

Comment: please mention it in question if you have any extra framework / JS used. also, the JS you use does not support `:focus+label`. If you intend to support OLD browsers, you shouldn't take the risk to use new technology. `onclick` with swapping image is already sufficient for your case.

Comment: thx u reply Shivan raptor, not only in ie7 is all browser also same problem now.

Comment: please update your questions (and what do you mean by all browsers?). Make a jsfiddle

Comment: now I can see the issue. the checkbox images are not showing correctly.

Comment: updated your jsfiddle to clearly illustrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/fdEHj/1/

Comment: is have any way to separate the label without using javascript? thx

Answer (score 0):

To show my own radio buttons instead of default once that changes according to browser, I used this: http://www.screwdefaultbuttons.com/

It works in IE6 + , Chrome, Firefox, Safari...

http://www.screwdefaultbuttons.com/

including script in header:

```
<script src="js/jquery.screwdefaultbuttonsV2.min.js" ></script>
```

css

```
    $('input:radio').screwDefaultButtons({ 
    image: "url(images/radio.jpg)",
    width:   85,
    height:  85
});

.styledRadio {
/* Your styles here */
}

.styledCheckbox {
    /* Your styles here */

}
```